# Embedding Tradingview widget in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget

I am an extremely beginner of Wordpress. I need to add a tradingview widget on my Wordpress page. Code as below.

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
 <span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Forex Heat Map by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
 <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-forex-heat-map.js">{
   "currencies": [
     "EUR",
     "USD",
     "JPY",
     "GBP",
     "INR"
   ],
   "width": "450",
   "height": "500",
   "locale": "en"
 }</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

The script part is usually suppressed by Wordpress. Please let me know if I can directly add widgets on Wordpress page. If by hooking in function.php if it could be done a sample code would be very useful. My given code works fine in plain html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to insert that script into a page, you could use a plugin or set up a custom field in ACF, but the easiest way is to create a **shortcode** that you can add into the post editor.

Create a function in **functions.php** to display the script, and then use `add_shortcode` to define the shortcode to use. e.g.:

```
/* function that just displays the script */
function insert_tradingview_heatmap_shortcode() { ?>
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Forex Heat Map by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
    <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-forex-heat-map.js">{
      "currencies": [
        "EUR",
        "USD",
        "JPY",
        "GBP",
        "INR"
      ],
      "width": "450",
      "height": "500",
      "locale": "en"
    }</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
<?php
}
/* create a shortcode called tradingview_heatmap that will run the function */
add_shortcode('tradingview_heatmap', 'insert_tradingview_heatmap_shortcode');
```

Then to display the heat map in a post/page, your just need to put the following shortcode into the post editor:

```
[tradingview_heatmap]
```

**UPDATE:**

It might help to get a very simple shortcode to work first, so we can rule out anything with it.

Add this to your functions.php:

```
/* function to display a test message */
function my_test_shortcode() { ?>
    <p>This is added by my test shortcode!</p>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('my_test_shortcode', 'my_test_shortcode');
```

Type the following into the post editor for a new, empty post, save it and view the post in your browser:

```
[my_test_shortcode]
```

It should print "This is added by my test shortcode!" as the post text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess I am missing something. I have registered the function using following code in function.php

Comment: @rajesh I tested that code and shortcode before I posted and it works perfectly. Did you put the code directly into functions.php as it is? There is no need to register anything. Also, did you test the shortcode in a new empty post or page (i.e. not a custom post type) using the standard post editor? Or are you trying to add it using PHP?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have registered the function using below cd in function.php (my theme)
function tv_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('forex', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tview.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tv_scripts' );
I added the given code in new js file tview.js under js folder, does not give error. But when I attempt to add shortcode [tradingview_heatmap] to text window of editor it doesnt give the result. How to put it in post editor? (I think I am asking dumb question) I have attempted a few post editor plugins including TinyMCE. Not sure how to use it.

Comment: You don't need to register the js because its included in the script. To put the shortcode into the post editor, you literally just type `[tradingview_heatmap]` where you would put the text! Just make sure its on its own line. To test the shortcode code first, I've updated the answer with a basic shortcode - try it and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: If I add the code (original or the updated) to function.php of my theme at the end, it crashes. 
Error sequence: 
{main}( ) in index.php
require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\MarketAnalysis\wp-admin\admin.php' ) in index.php
require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\MarketAnalysis\wp-load.php' ) in admin.php
require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\MarketAnalysis\wp-config.php' ) in wp_load.php
require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\MarketAnalysis\wp-settings.php' ) in wp-config.php
I am using latest wordpress version 2016 theme.

Comment: Strange. Try putting just this instead:`/* function to display a test message */
function my_test_shortcode() { ?> <p>This is added by my test shortcode!</p><? }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154464/discussion-between-rajesh-and-fluffykitten).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Forex Heat Map by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
    <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-forex-heat-map.js">{
      "currencies": [
        "EUR",
        "USD",
        "JPY",
        "GBP",
        "INR"
      ],
      "width": "450",
      "height": "500",
      "locale": "en"
    }</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Forex Heat Map by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
    <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-forex-heat-map.js">{
      "currencies": [
        "EUR",
        "USD",
        "JPY",
        "GBP",
        "INR"
      ],
      "width": "450",
      "height": "500",
      "locale": "en"
    }</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).